# Invalid use of group function with AVG function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, sqlite

I'm a bit new to SQL, it's my second day learning it. I am getting the error "ERROR 1111 HY000: Invalid use of group function"

The value of AVG(cost) is 450, so instead of doing this (which works)

```
SELECT name, seller_id, cost
FROM items
WHERE cost > 450;
```

I want this (doesn't work)

```
SELECT name, seller_id, cost
FROM items
WHERE cost > AVG(cost);
```

So why is the second one not working?

Sorry if this may seem like an obvious question, I am very new to SQL so I am still unfamiliar with the syntax and how the queries are interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to compute the average cost across the table:

```
SELECT name, seller_id, cost
FROM items
WHERE cost > (SELECT AVG(cost) FROM items)
```

Comment: It's better to place the suquery into the FROM section. SELECT name, seller_id, cost
FROM items i, (SELECT AVG(cost) as avg_cost FROM items) sub
WHERE i.cost > sub.avg_cost

Comment: @StanislavL I would expect the query optimizer, if well-written, to be able to figure out that the subquery has no correlation with the outer query, and to compute it once only, whether it appears in the `SELECT` list or the `WHERE` clause.